# Delete all files in a folder that weren't saved today in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, delete-file

I'm trying to delete all the files in a folder that have not been saved today.

The folder will only have **`.csv`** and **`.txt`** file types, so I made my code to delete just those types.  Is there a way to delete any file type?

This is the code that I have right now:

```
Sub delete()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFileTxt As String
Dim MyFileCSV As String

MyFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\pdf_converter_test"
MyFileTxt = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.txt")
MyFileCSV = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.csv")

Do While FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFileTxt) <> Date
     On Error Resume Next
       If FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFileTxt) <> Date Then
           Kill MyFolder & MyFileTxt
           MyFileTxt = Dir
       End If
Loop

Do While FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyCSV) <> Date
     On Error Resume Next
       If FileDateTime(MyFolder & MyFileCSV) <> Date Then
           Kill MyFolder & MyFileCSV
           MyFileCSV = Dir
       End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

The loop seems to go on forever, so there is a problem with the Do While condition.  But it also doesn't delete the files I want it to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You can't keep 2 "instances" of `Dir` like that.

Comment: Your question was answered but I still advise you never to use `On Error resume next` like that in a `Do While`... If you ever get any kind of error, you'll just skip it and the loop will run forever, always skipping the error. Very bad idea. You need some sort of exit mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most simplest way to achieve what you want. This will delete any file type which has not been saved today i.e it's modified date is not same as today.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object    
    Dim objfile As Object


    '~~> Change as needed
    sPath = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Test\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Format(objFile.DateLastModified, "DD-MM-YYYY") <> Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") Then
            Kill objFile
        End If
    Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `Kill objFile` as opposed to `objFile.Delete`?

Comment: @Comintern: Nope. It's more of a habit :D Besides KILLING is more fun than DELETING :P

Comment: I'm obviously very new to programming.  The "For Each" loop makes much more sense here.  The code is working perfectly.  Thank you.